# Better Emacs Toolbar Icons?

Tags: emacs

The Windows emacs toolbar icons are **ugly**. I just can't use it like this.

Where can I find better icons (like the ones I see in Ubuntu's Emacs) and how do I change them?

[image: Screenshot]

(I wasn't sure if this was better suited for SU or SO or not, so feel free to move it if that's the case.)

Comment: Build a gtk version?

Comment: I'd rather not build anything from scratch... I've had painful experiences with building *nix programs.

Answer (score 4):

Which Emacs build for Windows are you using? The GNU one? EmacsW32, which IIRC may have different icons?)

Actually after quite some time of using Emacs I finally went and simply turned off the toolbar. Given that your productivity in Emacs depends somewhat on you being able to drive it via the keyboard anyway, after a little while the toolbar only takes up screen real estate and you gain a couple of lines of code you can look at instead.

So my advice would be instead of spending time to hunt down an improved icon set I would suggest you add the following line to your .emacs and make use of the additional screen real estate :) :

```
(tool-bar-mode -1)
```

Comment: Eh... I'll do that when I become more pro at it... also, the icons are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding nice iconset to where Windows keep icon themes for GTK apps, like described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-406540.html).

Comment: Process Monitor is telling me that Emacs doesn't touch any GTk folder at all, so that wouldn't actually work. In fact, it seems like Emacs stores the pictures in its `\etc\images` folder, so that's the right place. But the question is: Where do I get the GTk-like icons in the right format? It seems like it's using its own "pixmap" format...

Comment: I am not an expert in Windows builds of Linux soft, but [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#LessTif-Resources) chapter, D6 says that emacs can be built without gtk widget set support...